# Tidying Dataset

Tags: r, tidyverse

Been struggling with tidying a dataset. Brief description: Each row represents one person, and then the columns repeat with "Date", "ScoreA", "ScoreB", etc. for all the dates that we have scores for. Hoping to get it to where all of the dates are in one column, and the corresponding scores are in adjacent columns. Have tried various combinations of simple pivot_longer or pivot_wider, with no success so far. A sample file is located at

https://github.com/tueland/R_help.git

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` after doing some `names_repair`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

nm1 <- sub("\\.?\\d+$", "", names(df1)[-1])
names(df1)[-1] <- paste0(nm1, "_", ave(nm1, nm1, FUN = seq_along))
df1 %>%
    select(-c("X_1", "X_2")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = c(".value", "group"), 
            names_sep="_", values_drop_na = TRUE ) %>% 
    na.omit
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#     ID group Date   ScoreA ScoreB ScoreC
#  <int> <chr> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1   123 1     1/1/11    1      2      3  
#2   123 2     1/2/11    4      5      6  
#3   123 3     1/4/11    6.1    6.2    6.3
#4   345 1     2/2/22    7      8      9  
#5   345 2     2/3/22   10     11     12
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map_dfr(1:3, ~ df1 %>%
                 select(ID, ends_with(as.character(.x))) %>% 
                 rename_all(~ str_remove(., "_\\d+$")))  %>% 
         select(-X) %>% 
         na.omit
#   ID   Date ScoreA ScoreB ScoreC
#1  123 1/1/11    1.0    2.0    3.0
#2  345 2/2/22    7.0    8.0    9.0
#6  123 1/2/11    4.0    5.0    6.0
#7  345 2/3/22   10.0   11.0   12.0
#11 123 1/4/11    6.1    6.2    6.3
```

---

Or with `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^Date", "ScoreA", 
   "ScoreB", "ScoreC", "^X"),
    value.name = c("Date", "ScoreA", "ScoreB", "ScoreC", "X"))[, X := NULL])
#    ID variable   Date ScoreA ScoreB ScoreC
#1: 123        1 1/1/11    1.0    2.0    3.0
#2: 345        1 2/2/22    7.0    8.0    9.0
#3: 123        2 1/2/11    4.0    5.0    6.0
#4: 345        2 2/3/22   10.0   11.0   12.0
#5: 123        3 1/4/11    6.1    6.2    6.3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tueland/R_help/master/R%20help.csv")
```

Comment: Perfect. Appreciate the help!